# JBossFuse - Fab installation and dependencies resolution

Tags: java, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I'm trying to install a bundle with a dependency to com.google.code.gson/gson/2.2.4. However when starting the bundle, I get the following message:

```
Error executing command: Error starting bundles:  
  Unable to start bundle 242: Unresolved constraint in bundle gopressComponants 
  [242]: Unable to resolve 242.0: missing requirement [242.0] osgi.wiring.package; 
  (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.gson)(version>=2.2.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
```

The bundle installation is done with the command:

```
install fab:mvn:com.audaxis.gopress/gopressComponants/0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
```

this is an extract of the MANIFEST.MF file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1391018962398
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_45
Built-By: david
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Camel Checksum Component
Bundle-SymbolicName: gopressComponants
Bundle-Version: 0.0.2.SNAPSHOT
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package: com.audaxis.camel.gopress.utils;uses:="com.google.gson.stream,
  com.google.gson";version="0.0.2.SNAPSHOT"
Import-Package: com.google.gson;version="[2.2,3)",
   com.google.gson.stream;version="[2.2,3)"
```

The gson jar is well located in the local maven repository.

Any idea, why the dependencies are not automatically installed ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have gson as a dependency in your maven pom.xml file. FAB uses that to know which dependencies you require

Comment: Yes, I have the gson dependecy in the pom.xml.
It works for some dependencies, but not for gson.

Comment: You can make your own bundle for the gson jar?

Comment: You can manually install gson first, have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, I can install Gson manually, then it works. But I've got the same issue for several other jars. And I would like to automate the installation process.